# Inconsistent Routing name generation in Rails default routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Leave` and a controller name '`LeavesController`'. When I set `resources :leave`[singular] to the `routes.rb` then the routes name are ok. But when I set the `resources :leaves`[plural], then I get some funny routing name. See screenshot for details. [*leafe, new_leafe, edit_leafe*]

How can I get rid of these funny routing name?

[image: This is when I set <code>resources :leaves</code> in routes.rb]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `config/initializers/inflections.rb` uncomment/add the following

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'leave', 'leaves'
end
```

**Explanation:**

Rails uses Inflectors to singularize/pluralize words automatically. This is how things like singular model names are transformed into their plural table names. Rails is typically able to guess the correct pluralization/singularization but can sometimes get confused. The `inflections.rb` initializer allows you to explicitly define how you want to handle singularization/pluralization when Rails doesn't give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. Been wondering for couple of hours why it is behaving like this. Can you please mention why rails behaves this way?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. :)

Comment: @user5756014 the rule is defined [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb#L41) it shows that if the word ends in `ves` then replace `ves` with `fe`